# Как перенаправлять на url через обычную кнопку aiogram, через инлайн не подходит?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="старт")
    async def cusotm(message: types.Message):
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button_1 = types.KeyboardButton(text="Культура")
        buttons = ["Звонки(менеджер)", "Игры(менеджер)", 'Поддержка(менеджер)']
        keyboard.add(*buttons)
        await message.answer("Привет мы компания которая занимается этим этим и тем и всем")
        time.sleep(2)
        await message.answer("О чем хотите узнать??", reply_markup=keyboard)
    @dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text =='Звонки(менеджер)')
    async def первый_менеджер(message: types.Message):
        await message.answer("Тут пока пусто")
```

Вот есть код, и нудно чтоб при нажатии на кнопку бот перенаправлял на менеджера по ссылке, это реализуемо?

Comment: Нет, обычные кнопки не могут так делать

Comment: Сделал костыль наверное, но ответ обновил. И старайтесь не использовать кириллицу в своем коде - это ужасный стиль и манера написания кода, которая не всегда будет компилироваться и выполнять программу, вообще не понимаю как это работало до этого ><